# Is nonnegativity necesssary in vectors giving a joint density matrix

Tags: probability

Consider the following: Show that if a joint density matrix $A$ has rank one, then $A = xy^T$ for some vectors $x$ and $y$ whose entries are nonnegative and sum to one.

My confusion has risen from the fact that if all entries in x and y are nonpositive, then all values in A are nonnegative meaning that the restriction while sufficient is not the whole story. Arguing that the values have to be nonnegative is trivial since we are dealing with probabilities, but does the problem have unnecessary restriction?

Comment: What, precisely, is a "joint density matrix"?  And, precisely, is the particular "unnecessary restriction" you are asking about?

Comment: @kimchilover I hope I am not butchering any terms, but by a joint density matrix I mean a matrix $A$ whose entry $A_{i,j}$ gives the probability for $P(X_1 = i, X_2 = j)$. 

With the  "unnecessary restriction" I was referring for the nonnegativity constraint placed on the entries of $x$ and $y$. I do not see why $x$ and $y$ cannot have nonpositive entries as long as they both have $only$ nonpositive entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a probability part to this question, and a linear algebra part.

The algebra part is, if the matrix $A$ has rank $1$, there exist vectors $u$ and $v$ such that $A=uv^T$, that is $A_{i,j}=u_i v_j$ for all $i,j.$  (How you reach this point depends on what you know about rank, and so on.  For instance,  let $u$ be a basis vector for the range of $A$, which is assumed to be one dimensional, etc.) Note that if $A=uv^T$ then also $A=(-u)(-v^T)$.

The probability part involves drawing conclusions from $\sum_{i,j}A_{i,j}=1$ and from $A_{i,j}\ge0, \forall i,j$.  From the former we know there exist $k,l$ for which $u_kv_l>0$, and hence $u_k\ne0, v_l\ne 0$.  From the latter we know $u_k$ and $v_l$ are either both strictly positive or both strictly negative. If $u_k>0$ then, since $u_k v_j\ge0, \forall j$, we know $y_j\ge0, \forall j$. If
$u_k<0$ then, since $u_k v_j\ge0, \forall j$, we know $y_j\le0, \forall j$.   In the first case, $x=u, y=v$ satisfies the claimed result.  In the second, $x=-u, y=-v$ satisfies the claimed result.

The explanation of your "unnecessary restriction" is that there is none.  A detailed description on the hypothesis side of an implication might qualify as an unnecessary restriction, but on on the conclusion side (as we have here) is simply a stronger, more detailed result.